# How to delete duplicates from 2nd level of array in Mongo DB

Tags: mongodb

I have duplicates in 2nd level of array.

In 2nd level array elements all the columns contains same data except _id. In Some cases _id also is same.

Please suggest how to delete duplicates from 2nd level of array by keeping one element.

From the below example we can treat AssessmentName as unique filed in Bhra array.

Mongo Version :  3.2.8
Example:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("592415c434810eeb63afe029"),
    "Encounter" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5846c6361489b54e402d76f6"),
            "Bhra" : [ 
                {
                    "_id" : "15445853419048538e0ba2cd",
                    "AssessmentId" : 1,
                    "AssessmentName" : "Major Depressive Episode",
                    "AssessmentOrder" : 1,
                    "IsContinue" : true,
                    "IsNotAssessed" : false,
                    "TotalScore" : 9,
                    "DepressionSeverity" : "Mild depression",
                    "AssessmentResult" : "Negative",
                    "Notes" : ""
                }, 
                {
                    "_id" : "15445853419048538e0ba2aa",
                    "AssessmentId" : 1,
                    "AssessmentName" : "Major Depressive Episode",
                    "AssessmentOrder" : 1,
                    "IsContinue" : true,
                    "IsNotAssessed" : false,
                    "TotalScore" : 9,
                    "DepressionSeverity" : "Mild depression",
                    "AssessmentResult" : "Negative",
                    "Notes" : ""
                }, 
                {
                    "_id" : "15445853419048538e0ba2aa",
                    "AssessmentId" : 1,
                    "AssessmentName" : "Major Depressive Episode",
                    "AssessmentOrder" : 1,
                    "IsContinue" : true,
                    "IsNotAssessed" : false,
                    "TotalScore" : 9,
                    "DepressionSeverity" : "Mild depression",
                    "AssessmentResult" : "Negative",
                    "Notes" : ""
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Output should be as follows.

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("592415c434810eeb63afe029"),
    "Encounter" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5846c6361489b54e402d76f6"),
            "Bhra" : [ 
                {
                    "_id" : "15445853419048538e0ba2cd",// any _id is fine
                    "AssessmentId" : 1,
                    "AssessmentName" : "Major Depressive Episode",
                    "AssessmentOrder" : 1,
                    "IsContinue" : true,
                    "IsNotAssessed" : false,
                    "TotalScore" : 9,
                    "DepressionSeverity" : "Mild depression",
                    "AssessmentResult" : "Negative",
                    "Notes" : ""
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Thanks, 
Rao

Comment: you can try unique index on Encounter.Bhra.AssessmentId

Comment: Tried to created unique index, but it didn't work and got an error saying column is having duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

You can use aggregation. First, you need to `$unwind` data 2 times in order to reach to level 2 array and then use `$group` to only include distinct item in array. Finally, `$project` into required json format.

```
db.your_collection.aggregate([
    {"$unwind":"$Encounter"},
    {"$unwind":"$Encounter.Bhra"},
    {"$group":{
            _id: {
                _id:"$_id",
                "Encounter_id":"$Encounter._id", 
                "Encounter_Bhra_AssessmentId":"$Encounter.Bhra.AssessmentId",
                "Encounter_Bhra_AssessmentName":"$Encounter.Bhra.AssessmentName",
                "Encounter_Bhra_AssessmentOrder":"$Encounter.Bhra.AssessmentOrder",
                "Encounter_Bhra_IsContinue":"$Encounter.Bhra.IsContinue",
                "Encounter_Bhra_IsNotAssessed":"$Encounter.Bhra.IsNotAssessed",
                "Encounter_Bhra_TotalScore":"$Encounter.Bhra.TotalScore",
                "Encounter_Bhra_DepressionSeverity":"$Encounter.Bhra.DepressionSeverity",
                "Encounter_Bhra_AssessmentResult":"$Encounter.Bhra.AssessmentResult",
                "Encounter_Bhra_Notes":"$Encounter.Bhra.Notes"
                },
            "Encounter_Bhra_id":{"$min":"$Encounter.Bhra._id"}
        }
    },
    {"$project":{
            _id:"$_id._id",
            Encounter : {
                _id:"$_id.Encounter_id",
                Bhra : {
                    _id : "$Encounter_Bhra_id",
                    AssessmentId : "$_id.Encounter_Bhra_AssessmentId",
                    AssessmentName : "$_id.Encounter_Bhra_AssessmentName",
                    AssessmentOrder : "$_id.Encounter_Bhra_AssessmentOrder",
                    IsContinue : "$_id.Encounter_Bhra_IsContinue",
                    IsNotAssessed : "$_id.Encounter_Bhra_IsNotAssessed",
                    TotalScore : "$_id.Encounter_Bhra_TotalScore",
                    DepressionSeverity : "$_id.Encounter_Bhra_DepressionSeverity",
                    AssessmentResult : "$_id.Encounter_Bhra_AssessmentResult",
                    Notes : "$_id.Encounter_Bhra_Notes"
                }
            }
        }    
    },
    {$out: "your_new_coll_name"}
])
```

Output:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("592415c434810eeb63afe029"),
    "Encounter" : {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5846c6361489b54e402d76f6"),
        "Bhra" : {
            "_id" : "15445853419048538e0ba2aa",
            "AssessmentId" : 1,
            "AssessmentName" : "Major Depressive Episode",
            "AssessmentOrder" : 1,
            "IsContinue" : true,
            "IsNotAssessed" : false,
            "TotalScore" : 9,
            "DepressionSeverity" : "Mild depression",
            "AssessmentResult" : "Negative",
            "Notes" : ""
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Ra Ka, I want to delete data from my collection.. is it possible ..?

Comment: @Rao if you want to modify your old data and migrate it to new collection which will contain new data with deleted duplicates, then you can use `$out` with aggregation as I have updated in answer. But, if you want to update in existing collection, since your document contain nested array, I'm afraid it may be not quite possible unless you know which index in the array contain duplicate data and explicitly delete it using `db.collection.update()`.